# routing & routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

I currently have an app that when a user signs up, it is being routed to index (basic/"Welcome Aboard" rails page)

In the users_controller.rb I have a create method with the following redirect:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
```

And in the routes files I have the following:

```
root :to => "users#new"
```

When a user creates a valid signup, it is to redirect to the users#new (basically the same page)  However, it is redirecting to the default index file in rails.

Any thoughts as to why it is doing this, what may I be missing?  I am pretty sure this is all the necessary info, but if more is need please let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the index.html file from the public folder.